# How can I get appdelegate's pointer in cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x

What I'm trying to ask is what code should be instead of "`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`" in cocos2d-x?

cocos2d-iPhone `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]`

cocos2d-x "???????????????"

I can't really find that way.... help

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for cocos2d-x iPhone projects easily. Just change the extension to .mm from .cpp. Then you can do the same code. :)
But .mm files don't work on Android.

Comment: YES, I knew it though, but Thanks~! I solved problem with just making the other class.